# Pass null to method in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, method

I tried declaring an empty string named `tocheck`, and I passed this variable to my method. This should cover the `else` clause in my code. However, this snippet is not covered. What else can I try to provide code coverage of my conditional statement?

[image: Full Coverage, except on <code>else</code> branch]

```
public static String sourceConfidence(String sourceSystemID){
        system.debug('sourceSystemID'+sourceSystemID);
        if(sourceSystemID != '' ||sourceSystemID != null){
            try{
                Source_System_Configuaration__c  result = [SELECT Source_Confidence__c FROM Source_System_Configuaration__c WHERE System_Id__c= :sourceSystemID];
                sourceConfidence=Integer.valueOf(result.Source_Confidence__c);

            }catch(Exception e){
                system.debug(e);
                return '0';
        }
        }else {
        return '0';
        }


    return String.ValueOf(sourceConfidence);

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a **condition** ambiguity in the code. You want to prevent `null` and `blank` to enter in main code.

But `if(sourceSystemID != '' ||sourceSystemID != null)` will not work. If you pass a `null`, it will make the first condition `true` and let the code enter in main code.
If you pass `blank` then it will make second condition `true` and let the code enter in main code.

I will suggest to change the condition as:

```
if(sourceSystemID != ''  && sourceSystemID != null) // check with AND
{
   // bla
}
```

[Kieth C](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/887/keith-c)'s suggestion (better):

```
if(!String.isEmpty(sourceSystemID)) // check both null and blank
{
   // bla
}
```

Now you can pass:

```
ClassName.sourceConfidence(null); // This
ClassName.sourceConfidence(''); // or this
```